# How to create specify typescript RN version?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-typescript

I type the command to create React Native project with typescript.

```
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

package.json

`"react-native": "0.63.2"`

I want to create 0.62.2 with typescript so I try the command:

```
npx react-native init MyApp --version 0.62.2 --template react-native-template-typescript
```

package.json

`"react-native": "0.63.0"`

It is 0.63.0 not 0.62.2

Why I can't create 0.62.2 with typescript ?

Answer (score 21):

For typescript template, the version of react native depends on the react-native-template-typescript version, for example:

- react-native-template-typescript@6.5.9 --> react-native@0.63.4
- react-native-template-typescript@6.5.7 --> react-native@0.63.3

Therefore if you want to install version react-native@0.63.4, you need to apply the command like this:

```
npx react-native init AwesomeTSProject --template react-native-template-typescript@6.5.9
```

more info:
[react-native-template-typescript releases](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-template-typescript/releases)

Comment: This one works for me `--template react-native-template-typescript@6.5.*`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just spent a bunch of time trying to get it to work myself, and this is what worked:

```
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript@6.4.* --version 0.62.2
```

Note the specific version of the template package. To find the right template version for other versions of React Native, see https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-template-typescript#usage-with-older-versions-of-react-native.

If a **wrong version is still getting installed**, it's most likely you have another version of `react-native` installed globally. Run `npm uninstall -g react-native react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli` (whatever you installed previously), and make sure `which react-native` returns an empty result.

---

Previous incorrect answer:

> <strike>I believe the correct syntax for having `npx` run a specific package version is:</strike>
>
> ```
> npx react-native@0.62.2 init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can instead install a specific version of react-native on your machine using `npm i -g react-native@0.62.2` and then run `react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript` (without `npx`).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but try the npx react-native@0.62.2 init... , the result is still `"react-native": "0.63.0"`, it looks like version position is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have given some time to solve this situation.
[Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-template-typescript)

> So I wanted to install 0.63.4 version of React-native, so I use supported typescript version for react native project

```
  npx react-native init serialPort --template react-native-template-typescript@6.5
```

And react native project base 0.64 has installed.

Answer (score -1):

Try please,

```
npx react-native init MyApp --version react-native@0.62.2 --template react-native-template-typescript
```

Comment: Thanks I try the command, the result is still `"react-native": "0.63.0"`

Comment: This does not work for me, the script installs the latest version of RN, no the one which mentioned in the flag