# npx react-native init creates app with wrong version of React Native

Tags: react-native

Using the following command:
`npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript --version 0.63.4`

or

`npx react-native init MyApp --version 0.63.4 --template react-native-template-typescript`

creates an app using React Native 0.68.2 - I need version 0.63.4 - what is the correct command?

Update - I have tried this command:
`npx react-native init ExperienceApp --template react-native-template-typescript@6.5.9` as described here: [How to create specify typescript RN version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63150695/how-to-create-specify-typescript-rn-version)

but I get the error:

> error Couldn't find any versions for "react-native-template-typescript" that matches "6.5.9"

and I have tried this as in the docs: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-template-typescript#usage-with-older-versions-of-react-native

`npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript@6.5.*`

but I get the error:

> no matches found: react-native-template-typescript@6.5.*

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing this: `npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript@6.5.*` to this `npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript@6.5`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

npx react-native@0.65 init MyTestApp --version 0.65 --template react-native-template-typescript@6.7

Change versions as per need